# Best place to locate image resources for vaadin app?

Tags: tomcat, tomcat7, vaadin, vaadin7

Where is the best place to locate image resources for a vaadin 7 app?

1. Is it /var/lib/tomcat7/webapps/imageFolder/?
2. How should I set permissions for this folder?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Recommended path is WebContent/WEB-INF/images, but you can put them wherever you want.
From [Book of Vaadin](https://vaadin.com/book/vaadin7/-/page/application.resources.html)

[image: Image resources path]

Comment: Thanks!!!....but what if I want the images to be available to more than one vaadin app?...what about permits for this folder?

Answer (score 0):

I would add static images under the theme folder of the application and then use `ThemeResource`s to reference the images in Java code.

For example if the image is in `WebContent/VAADIN/themes/mytheme/image.png` then the application must use theme `mytheme`, and a `ThemeResource` would look as follows:

```
new ThemeResource("image.png");
```